# windows10 user cannot run python, only admin

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-10, conda

I've been trying to get this to work using google all day to no avail.
python works fine in a cmd as admin but my user can't run it (also vs code doesn't work), tried to set the variable permanently but nothing works. I still have a very old python path in my pythonhome/path variable and when I change it, it reverts back at the next cmd start.
It works temporarily after setting it with `set pythonpath=C:\PROGRAMDATA\PYTHON\PYTHON39`
but then of course not the next time and also not in VS code

sorry if this isn't enough information, I'll be glad to deliver anything further needed

[image]

Comment: why not keep admin and user separate, and make a "normal" user installation of Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you only add the path to Administrator.

Open Environment Variables, In **User variable for username**, choose **Path**, click **New**, then past the pythonpath :

[image]

Comment: thanks, because im using a german version of windows i never got the windows search results to show me that there was a second "version" for the current user.

Comment: Glad my answer helped you. Happy Coding:)