# Python Not found (VSCODE)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I installed the code runner extension in Visual Studio Code and tried user input(In terminal) But then it said Python was not found. Run without arguments to install from Microsoft Store or inactivate this shortcut from Settings > Manage Alias For running programs. I tried finding this Manage Alias for running programs but I couldn't find it. How do I fix that I can't run a program?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your vscode window

Comment: Have you added Python to **PATH**? Please follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65202021/windows10-user-cannot-run-python-only-admin/65213595#65213595) and see if the error goes away.